# How $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}$ exists?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

How $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}$$ exists?

It is difficult question to me. i have tried to evaluate by using fact that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \ dx =\int_{-\infty}^{0} f(x)\, dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)\, dx$$ but i have failed in this one.   any hints on this one?

Comment: Hint: What is the derivative of $\arctan[x]$?

Comment: ohhh. you are genius man. thank you

Comment: wait a minute, how i know that $\arctan x $ exist at $\lim_{x \to \infty} \arctan x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track. We have

$$\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{1}{1 + x^2}\, dx = \lim_{a\to -\infty} \int_a^0 \frac{1}{1 + x^2}\, dx = \lim_{a\to -\infty} \arctan x\bigg|_{x = a}^0 = \lim_{a\to -\infty} (-\arctan a) = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

and

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1 + x^2}\, dx = \lim_{b \to \infty}\int_0^b \frac{1}{1 + x^2}\, dx = \lim_{b\to \infty} \arctan x\bigg|_{x = 0}^b = \lim_{b\to \infty} \arctan b = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Therefore $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1 + x^2}\, dx$ exists and has value $\frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{\pi}{2} = \pi$.

Comment: what about for $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac1{\sqrt{1+x^3}}$$

Comment: @Preta it does not exist (as a real number) because $\sqrt{1 + x^3}$ is not defined for $x < -1$. However, the integral $\int_{-1}^\infty \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1 + x^3}}$ does exist.

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$\int_{-X}^{X}\frac1{(1+x^2)}dx=2\int_{0}^{X}\frac1{(1+x^2)}dx= 2 \arctan X$$
then use
$$
\lim_{X\to+\infty}\arctan X=\frac{\pi}{2}
$$

Comment: how i prove that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \arctan x = \frac\pi2$$

Comment: @Preta this is a good exercise for you to look into. Remember what the definition of $\arctan$ is

Comment: okay i will do. thank you for much help generous men

Comment: @Preta Ok, just because $$ \lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}^-}\tan x=\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}^-}\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}= \frac{1}{0^+}=+\infty$$

Comment: @DanZimm Please, I don't understand what you say. Here $\tan$ takes $(-\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2)$ to $(-\infty, +\infty)$ and $\arctan$ does the reverse.

Comment: okay, i have follow up question for you gentlemens. how do i prove that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac1{\sqrt{1+x^3}}$$exist

Comment: @OlivierOloa I don't want to argue about it here, but I personally feel that this is a lacking argument.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach:$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^2}=\oint_C \frac{1}{1+z^2}=2\pi i\mathrm{Res}(f(z),i)= 2\pi i\times \frac{-i}{2}=\pi$$
where $C$ is a counterclockwise contour.

For your follow up question:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac1{\sqrt{1+x^3}}$$ is not expressible in terms of elementary functions.